# How to impose contraints between columns and rows in data in R?

Tags: r, tibble

The following code generates a list of tibbles that contain start, `s`, and end, `e`, ranges.

```
library(tidyverse)
tbl1 <- tibble(
  s = c(1, 4, 7, 10),
  e = c(3, 6, 8, 12),
  lbl = c("a", "a", "a", "a")
)

tbl2 <- tibble(
  s = c(1, 2, 5, 8),
  e = c(3, 4, 6, 10),
  lbl = c("b", "b", "b", "b")
)

tbls <- list(tbl1, tbl2)
```

I want to impose a contraint that checks if none of the  rows are overlapping within the list of tibbles. If it does exist, it should output which rows break the rule. I can only think about doing this with complicated for loops.

EDIT:

The rule should only be applied within `lbl` groups. The rule should not hold across the entire list of tibbles.

Comment: Could specify which rows break the overlapping rule? tbl2 - rows 1 & 2?

Comment: `tbl1` does not break the rule. `tbl2` breaks the rule at rows 1 and 2. [1,3] and [2,4] overlap. Also, I should add that the rule should only apply within the same `lbl`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An option using `lead` and `lag` can be as:

```
bind_rows(tbls, ) %>% group_by(lbl) %>%
  arrange(lbl, s) %>%
  filter(s <= lag(e, default = 0) | e >= lead(s, default = +Inf) )

# # A tibble: 2 x 3
# # Groups: lbl [1]
#      s     e lbl  
#   <dbl> <dbl> <chr>
# 1  1.00  3.00 b    
# 2  2.00  4.00 b
```